# Warning while compiling pthread_join on my machine ubuntu 16.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I'm getting these errors while I include the `pthread` library:

> implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_created’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  pthread_created(&id1,0,thread2,NULL);
>
> undefined reference to `pthread_created' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void* thread1(void* args)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}

void* thread2(void* args)
{
    int i = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2!= 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t id, id1;
    printf("before thread 1 is created");
    pthread_create(&id, 0, &thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(id, 0);
    printf("after thread 1 is created\n");
    printf("before thread 2 is created");
    pthread_created(&id1, 0, thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(id1, 0);
    printf("after thread2 is created");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a linker error. How are you linking this?

Answer (score 1):

When compiling with gcc, use the `-lpthread` flag.

For example:

```
gcc -o main main.c -lpthread
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo:

`pthread_created` is not `pthread_create`